# Getting started with Symfony2.8 as a MicroFramework (MicroKernel)

Tags: php, symfony

So I want to give this new version of Symfony (`2.8.0`) a try by using one of its new features: [*Symfony as a Microframework*](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-symfony-as-a-microframework).

The tutorial on Symfony's website is pretty straightforward. However, I cannot get started with it. I still get the default landing webpage.

I've followed every steps of the cookbook, that is to say **setting up `./app/MicroKernel.php`**. The content of the file is the exact same code as the one provided in the first *Hello World* application exemple so I won't be pasting it here.

I also updated **`./web/app.php`** with the following code, as per the cookbook:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/MicroKernel.php';

$app = new MicroKernel('prod', false);
$app->loadClassCache();

$app->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

I also cleared the cache:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
 // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false
 [OK] Cache for the "prod" environment (debug=false) was successfully cleared.
```

My virtual host is properly configured:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/steve-david.sf2/web/"
    ServerName "steve-david.sf2"

  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/steve-david.sf2/web/">
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I access to `http://steve-david.sf2/`, I land on the *Welcome to Symfony2.8.0* default webpage:

[image]

I didn't make any other change to the application downloaded with composer.

What am I missing here? Do I have to change anything in `./src/AppBundle/`? The lack of documentation about this new feature doesn't help either.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Somewhat offtopic: Symfony 3.0 is already available.

Comment: @ThomasLandauer: [Symfony2.8 is LTS whereas Symfony3 is not](http://symfony.com/roadmap). That is to say that support for v2.8 will be much longer than for v3. There *are* pros to use v2.8 over v3.

Comment: I was just thinking: Maybe it's a bug and they fixed it meanwhile ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cleared the cache with `php app/console` - and - from what I can see - you started with Symfony Standard Edition. It means that the `console` file runs commands in the default AppKernel instead of your new MicroKernel. Go and edit that file and replace `AppKernel` with `MicroKernel`. Then, run the `clear:cache` command. Just to be sure, delete the contents of `app/cache/*` directory.

It is not stated in the "cookbook" about that because it is not a tutorial of "how to change Symfony Standard Edition into a Microframework" but just "How to use the MicroKernelTrait".

By starting with Symfony Standard Edition you have files your MicroKernel won't need. Just delete AppKernel.php, AppCache.php. The `app/config` directory is also not needed at all. The `./src/AppBundle/` is redundant as well.

---

**Instead of Symfony Standard Edition** you should have just create an empty directory, and run `composer require symfony/symfony` there. Then create `app/MicroKernel.php` and `web/app.php` as in the tutorial. You will also need `app/autoload.php` file with the following contents (these lines about annotations are not needed in the starting example but you will probably need them later - without annotations support you can just skip creating this file and include `vendor/autoload.php` file directly):

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

And that's it. It should just work.